# Save GIF with Animation package {R}

Tags: r, animation

I would like to save a set of maps as gif with the `animation` package. I produce these maps for different years through a function I created. The function works.

However, I don't manage to save the output as a gif. This is what I coded:

```
i<- 1 

saveGIF(
  for(i in 1955:1957)
    multiplePlots(i),

  interval = .65,
  movie.name = "test.gif",
  img.name="test",
  convert = "convert"
)
```

The error is the following (copy-pasted from the console, I hope it helps):

```
Executing: 
""C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\convert.exe" -loop 0 -delay 65 test1.png test2.png test3.png "test.gif""
convert.exe: unable to load module `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': Le module spécifié est introuvable.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: unable to load module `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': Le module spécifié est introuvable.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: unable to load module `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': Le module spécifié est introuvable.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: no images defined `test.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3252.
an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
[1] FALSE
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 65 test1.png test2.png test3.png "test.gif""' had status 1 
2: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  '""C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 65 test1.png test2.png test3.png "test.gif""' execution failed with error code 1
3: running command '""C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 65 test1.png test2.png test3.png "test.gif""' had status 127 
4: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="test.gif": Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

In case you are wondering, I have ImageMagick installed.

Many thanks.